# How to make a fragment dialog draggable on an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, dialog, fragment

So, I am developing this app that needs a dialog screen over a map that chooses an item and is dragabble, that means that it can go up or down. How can I do that?

A good example is the instagram share button.[image: Instagram help screen]

Answer (score 0):

The component you want to use is a `BottomSheetDialog`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialog

This type of dialog has native support for being dragged.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Do you know if it's possible to disable the touch outside of screen and dialog still be dragable?

Comment: `BottomSheetDialog` has a method called `setCanceledOnTouchOutside()`. Set that to false.